# pentaho: Error processing component : how to set parameter for piechart?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I want to make a dynamic piechart (that depends on date parameter) on dashboard on CDE.
First, here's an example of my BD:

```
    ID    date       category
   ----------------------------
    1   2019-01-01    positive
    2   2019-01-01    positive
    3   2019-01-01    negative
    4   2019-01-01     zero
    1   2019-02-01    positive
    2   2019-02-01    zero
    3   2019-02-01    negative
```

On datasource panel, I added a query below:

```
select category, count(category) from table where date=${date} group by category;
```

Then on component panel, I did :
[image]

On Datasource panel, I set the parameter in the same way:
[image]

But the piechart doesn't show and the error message is : Error processing component
If I replace the parameter ${month} with a value like '2019-01-01', the pie chart does show without problem.

I followed multiple tutorials but can't resolve my problem.

Is it because of date format ?

This is how I set date parameter on datasource panel:I also tried with Date instead of String...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience is that treating CDE parameters as strings and then converting them to date in the SQL query works best and gives you the most control.

MySQL example:

```
where STR_TO_DATE(${DATE_FROM}, '%d-%m-%Y') = MyDateColumn
```

In my case, I needed to show "dd-mm-yyyy" format in the dashboard and internationalization is rather broken in CDE, so I went with string parameters and the above contains the MySQL date format for it. If you use a different DB, look up the date conversion function in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :) so I changed to query to "... where date=TO_DATE(${date}, ‘YYYY-MM-DD’) ..." since I'm using postgresql. However it doesn't make any difference :(

Comment: I actually wonder if I should set any parameter on Select Component, there are "Parameter", "Listeners","Parameters" and they are left blank.

Comment: Listeners = the parameters that trigger a refresh of the chart if changed. Parameters = Pass these to the data source (date should be among them!)

Comment: Oops, misread, you said select, not chart. On a select component you only fill them if for example the choices in one depend on another selection, requiring refreshes.

Comment: hey! I tried again and it works now. The problem was indeed with date format so I used TO_DATE function and also at first I didn't set parameter on Select component. After setting it to "param_month", It works fine. Thanks a lot for your help!!